Why in "Breaking Bad" Season 5 does Skyler's house get taken away?
Why in Breaking Bad Season 5 does Skyler's house get taken away?
I don't get it. Walt's last phone call makes the police believe Skyler is an innocent victim forced into doing this for Walt and that she's not involved with what he did. So why did she get punished? Why did the government take away her house? Was it because she used Walt's drug money to pay the ongoing house expenses?

Yeah, I can't really see that this is not a duplicate.  Just wrote my answer while you made that comment.

oh my god , I'm so sorry , I'm not aware that this question has already been asked

Its no big deal .... don't worry about it.

Its not "her" house, it's "their" house. Even during the period Walt doesn't live there its quite unlikely that they took Walt's name off the Title. So formally he is still one of the owners. They never actually get divorced, so there would not be something forcing a change in ownership.
Its not clearly stated, but its quite likely that they didn't own the house outright and had a mortgage. While he clearly had enough money to pay the mortgage balance entirely, it's very probable they didn't do that because it would be suspicious. So in the event of Walt's activities becoming public knowledge, it's likely that Skyler could not afford to pay the mortgage.
It seems unlikely that it would be foreclosed so quickly, but given the state of the damage to the house and the possibility of her being in arrears with the mortgage payment, it may be that she is abandoning the house to live somewhere cheaper.
Also, while the authorities don't have enough evidence to prosecute her, it is possible they don't believe her to be innocent.
